# (Laravel) How can I return a variable to the .blade.php view with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When the user changes the category with the select field, I want to only show the requests with that category on the view--and to do this using an AJAX request. I want to pass the object that is being returned from the Controller to AJAX's success handler into the view (the $requests variable as seen in the code below), and for the view to update the requests shown.

The data is being returned to AJAX's success handler correctly as I can console.log the object, but it doesn't update the $requests variable.

*How do I achieve this, and what am I missing here?*

**The view that shows the requests from the DB**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

{{-- Requests --}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row requests-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>New requests</h2>
            <select name="category" class="form-control category">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a category...</option>
                <option value="Electronics and Computers">Electronics and Computers</option>
                <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
            </select>
            <hr>
            <p class="block"></p>
            @foreach ($requests as $request)
                @include('components.requests')
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

**The AJAX Request**

```
$('.category').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/category",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("Error: " + data);
        },
    });
});
```

**The controller on the backend that handles the AJAX request**

```
public function changeCategory(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::where('category', $request->category)->get();
    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: If you're not looking for a code writing service, may I ask what you would expect the code you posted to accomplish?  What would you anticipate happening in the AJAX success handler function currently?

Comment: Without ajax, you can submit the value of `category ` to current page, and loop `$posts` variable in your template

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to reload the page--that's why I chose to go with ajax instead of just using a route that re-renders the view with the updated variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `template` blade is php and ajax is from `client side` javascript.

So if you want to display something you need to use `javascript` to do it.

Maybe something like

```
success: function(data) {
    var posts = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, post) {
       posts += '<div class="post">' + post.title + '</div>';
    });
    $('.requests-row .col-md-12').prepend(posts);
}
```

Comment: I figured it was a way doing it without rewriting the code from the template, but maybe there's not? Any other way of achieving this that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

May be smth like that?

```
if($request->ajax()){
    return response()->json(['ajax']);
}
```

Comment: I've tried »return json_encode($requests), but that doesn't do anything. Is that what you were thinking?